# Finding three closest points in layer to each polygon in another layer using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, proximity

I am working with two layers in ArcMap 10.

One is a point layer and the other is a polygon layer. For each polygon I need to find the three closest points.

What is the best way to compile a list that gives each polygon and the three closest points?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ArcInfo license, you can use the  Near (Analysis) or Generate Near Table (Analysis) tools using the point layer as the input features and the polygon layer as the near features and sort.